# System.ObjectDisposedException when the button style is set to FlatStyle.System in WinForms application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, exception, button

`System.ObjectDisposedException` when the button style is set to `FlatStyle.System` in WinForms application

I've a child form which shows up on clicking a button in parent. And the code goes like below.

```
Public Class Parent

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOpenChild_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOpenChild.Click
        Child.Show()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The child form has in turn a button that closes itself.

```
Public Class Child
    Private Sub btnCloseMe_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCloseMe.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Steps to get exception:

- In debug mode, put a break point on `Me.Close()`
- Then click close button of child.
- On hit of break point open notepad and
- Comeback to solution then continue

Exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232798
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'Button'.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  ObjectName=Button
  StackTrace:
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PointToScreen(Point p)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
       at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
       at WindowsApplication2.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Does anyone has any idea, this is explicitly coming when button style set to `FlatStyle.System`

Comment: Is this causing a problem in your application or just curiosity?

Comment: In my realtime application on close click there is a long running process that goes for atleast 10 to 15 seconds. Meanwhile if the user clicks on any other application like notepad or word document or chrome this error pops up.

Comment: Debugging UI has a knack for causing problems like this.  A debugger break in itself has way to get events to fire differently, it can cause focusing and painting events.  In this case, activating another process is the trigger.  I assume it has something to do with the Capture property, critical to buttons.  In extreme cases it can be necessary to use the remote debugger so the debugger itself cannot affect the UI.  This is not such an extreme case, simply not starting Notepad is the workaround.  Just keep motoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly, it's a bug. The `Button`/`ButtonBase` internal implementation maintains some mouse state related flags which are not properly cleared in that case. `FlatStyle.System` seems to be a special case involving a lot of branches in the source code, so apparently some of them is missing something.

The workaround would be to create and use your own `Button` subclass like this (sorry for C#, I'm sure you can translate it to VB):

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    {
        if (this.IsDisposed) return;
        base.OnMouseUp(mevent);
    }
}
```